# ORACLE SQL Query only Overlapping Timeframes

Tags: sql, oracle, overlapping, date-range

**Data From `Emp` table:**

```
NUM  DEPT   HIRED_SDT                       HIRED_EDT
---  -----  ------------------------------  ------------------------------
1    Sales  October, 01 2012 11:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 11:30:00+0000
2    Sales  October, 01 2012 11:22:00+0000  October, 01 2012 12:40:00+0000
3    Sales  October, 01 2012 13:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 13:50:00+0000
4    CC     October, 01 2012 14:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 15:00:00+0000
5    CC     October, 01 2012 15:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 16:10:00+0000
6    CC     October, 01 2012 16:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 17:20:00+0000
```

**Desired Result:**

Only the overlapping timeframes grouped per departement

==> eg. within `Sales` there are 2 out of 3 records overlapping

```
NUM  DEPT   HIRED_SDT                       HIRED_EDT
---  -----  ------------------------------  ------------------------------
1    Sales  October, 01 2012 11:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 11:30:00+0000
2    Sales  October, 01 2012 11:22:00+0000  October, 01 2012 12:40:00+0000
5    CC     October, 01 2012 15:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 16:10:00+0000
6    CC     October, 01 2012 16:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 17:20:00+0000
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91730/1

Comment: Why October-11:22 and October-12:40 are overlapping and 13:00 and 13:50 are not? What is overlapping?

Comment: @Art: I believe, HIRED_SDT holds start dates and HIRED_EDT end dates. Ranges in rows 1 and 2 overlap because the second one starts between the first one's SDT & EDT.

Comment: @Andriy M - Thanks Andriy, I still don't get it but it is OK. In the example above I see the time diff of 78 minutes is overlapping but time diff of 50 minutes is not... Maybe I'm missing something... day dreaming as usual... LOL.

Comment: @Art: I think I can see your confusion. It's about ranges overlapping *one another*. Ranges 3 and 4 do not overlap any other ranges in their respective departments, that's why they should not be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Emp e
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Emp
  WHERE DEPT = e.DEPT
    AND HIRED_SDT < e.HIRED_EDT
    AND HIRED_EDT > e.HIRED_sDT
    AND NUM <> e.NUM
);
```

I.e. select a row if another row exists that belongs to the same department and has a range overlapping with this row's one.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `AND num <> e.num` in your `EXISTS`-clause, otherwise all rows are returned.